# What does the logic statement "F = AB" mean? Bitwise A AND B?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, alu

On an ALU data sheet there are logic formulae showing the results that will be output for various inputs.

http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1840939.pdf

(Second from last row on page 3.)

I assume that `A+B` means bitwise `A OR B`, this would follow, as the plus in a circle is `XOR`.

Does `AB` mean bitwise `A AND B`?

Comment: It would follow, because the arithmetic plus is indicated by `PLUS`. And since the multiplication is not among the parts capability (as indicated on the first page), `AB` would mean bitwise `A AND B`.

Comment: A lot of sources are already on the google search, no offense I don't think there is a question here.

Comment: Unless it is a regex expression your deduction is true.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, when written as multiplication in normal math, it means AND in Boolean logic.  This does make some sense when you think about it.  Make a truth table of multiplying two value that can be either 0 or 1.  The result is 0 except when both are 1, then the result is 1.  That's exactly what AND does.

This logic doesn't really follow for "+", unless you consider 0 FALSE and anything else TRUE.

Comment: So many words instead just yes

Comment: A one word answer is pretty much considered useless, and quickly downvoted.  Points for the explanation.

Comment: `unless you consider 0 FALSE and anything else TRUE` Like most C-derived programming languages, for example :)

Answer (score 4):

You are right `AB` mean `A AND B` . It is faster to write `AB` than `A dot B` or `A AND B`

Comment: Is it also faster to write "right" than it is to write "write" right?

Comment: @BenVoigt Didn't realize the edit, filled the comment box with alternating "right" and "write" to measure typing speed. Only then I noticed the earlier revision.